# Carrier is add up in cart

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have a big problem that I don´t understand.

I have add 3 different carrier.
1. Letter (Price: 60 Skr) range: 0-1kg
2. COD (Price: 200 Skr) range: 1-10000kg
3. Company package (Price: 595 Skr) range: 10000-100000kg

Then i have 3 products:
Product 1a weight: 0.001
Product 2a weight: 1
Product 3a weight: 10000

I whant when someone is ordering product 1a the shippping is 60 Skr. and payment is check. So far this works.
And if someone is ordering 1a + 2a the shipping shoud be 200 (The higgest of this two) and the payment is COD, the shipping goes to 260 Skr, and i see all 3 payment.

it´s like the 2 shipping is adding together.

I borrow payments to carrier from a friend to see if this works.
And i still see the 3 payment, and shipping is 260 Skr.

Is there a way of make the shipping NOT adding together in the cart...

Answer (score 0):

in product->Product 1a->shipping / delivery sub-menu select the right carrier.

ok i have made the same test as you : 
in each of your carriers in step 2 the option Out-of-range behavior should be setup to disable carrier.

Comment: Hello
I have try that...

This is product 
1a http://prntscr.com/eb515v, 2a http://prntscr.com/eb51mo, 3a http://prntscr.com/eb50a9

And it doesent work

Comment: can you show the screenshot of the 4th step of the carrier setup?

Comment: this is for the letter carrier : http://prntscr.com/eb7cpt, COD: http://prntscr.com/eb7dbg, Company package: http://prntscr.com/eb7dqf

Comment: I have this on prestashop.com - https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/594610-shipping-and-payment-based-on-specific-products/

Comment: I have manage to fix the shipping fee in the cart right.
But I still see all the payments.
It shoud only be one.